# How to add image dimensions a data attribute in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a responsive gallery in wordpress. First I added this line of code in my `functions.php` file:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    add_image_size('grid-1', 400, 9999);
    add_image_size('grid-2', 800,9999);
}
```

On a nother question here, I found that `9999` would allow Wordpress to crop the image in any hight in order for the image to not lose information. The day I can display it is:

```
the_post_thumbnail('grid-1')
```

the end result that I need to have is:

```
<img src="200x100.png" data-1x="400x200.png" data-2x="800x400.png">
```

Due to the fact that I would not know the hight, I would not be able to hard code that in. Is there a way to extract that information and add it to the `the_post_thumbnail('grid-1')`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but I think it should help you.

```
$grid_1 = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'grid-1', false ); 
$grid_2 = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'grid-2', false );
```

Then, your HTML would be something like this:

```
<img src="<? echo $grid_1[0]; ?> foo="<? echo echo $grid_2[0]; ?>" />
```

For futher informations, I recommend you to read Wordpress Codex article about [wp_get_attachment_image](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image).

Comment: thanks a lot,just some modification needed and I got it working fantastically `$grid_1 = 
wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'grid-1');` - that helped me a lot